# Prevent Asset Transforms from scaling Image past 100%

Tags: assets, image-transforms

There is almost never a reason why I would want an image to be scaled past 100% by a transform. This usually results in an image being looking worse than it would if scaled by the browser. Is there a way to tell Craft not to scale an image past 100% of its original size, even if the transform width is larger?

Comment: Please vote for this feature request to prevent transforms from scaling up! http://feedback.craftcms.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/10007034-image-transforms-have-option-not-to-scale-up

Comment: This feature request has been moved to GitHub: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/844

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.

[getWidth](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/assetfilemodel#getWidth) will give you an image's width: `{% set originalWidth = image.getWidth(false) %}`. You want to apply the transform if `desiredWidth` is less than `originalWidth`. I would write a [twig macro](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html):

```
{% macro transform(image, desiredWidth) %}
  {% set originalWidth = image.getWidth(false) %}
  {% if desiredWidth < originalWidth %}
    {{ image.getUrl({mode: 'fit', width: desiredWidth}) }}
  {% else %}
    {{ image.getUrl() }}
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

You could also do the same test, and then conditionally [setTransform](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/assetfilemodel#setTransform) on the image.

If you [define your transforms in the CP](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/image-transforms#defining-transforms-from-the-control-panel) the macro would be like this:

```
{% macro transform(image, transformHandle) %}
  {% set originalWidth = image.getWidth(false) %}
  {% set transformedWidth = image.getWidth(transformHandle) %}
  {% if transformedWidth < originalWidth %}
    {{ image.getUrl(transformHandle) }}
  {% else %}
    {{ image.getUrl() }}
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: Good answer. Would be nice, though, if this was a setting built into Transforms.

Comment: @cmal it looks like a setting to prevent upscaling [is already on "The List"](https://plus.google.com/110881688132908256910/posts/FAzrGAJ99W7).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a slight revision that checks widths and heights and ensures that the output has no white space:

```
{%- macro imageURL(image, transform) -%}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% if image.getWidth > image.getWidth(transform) or image.getHeight > image.getHeight(transform) %}
            {{ image.getUrl(transform) }}
        {% else %}
            {{ image.getUrl }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endspaceless %}
{%- endmacro -%}
```

Template usage:

```
{% import "_macros" as utils %}

<img src="{{ utils.imageURL(asset, 'medium') }}">
```

Answer (score 2):

In Craft 3 there's another way of doing it.
Brandon explained it [here](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/844)

```
{% set transformDimensions = craft.app.assetTransforms.getTransformByHandle('contentWidth') %}
{% set transform = {
    width: min(transformDimensions.width, image.width),
    mode: 'fit'
} %}

<img src="{{ image.url(transform) }}" alt="" />
```