# Image Transforms - disable scaling up

Tags: image-transforms

I have image transforms set up and working well for my site, however I have an issue that seems to be a possible feature request because it is not documented or on this Stack Exchange.

If a user uploads an image that is smaller than the image transform setting, it scales the image up for them to the specified size. However this results in a pixellated image because of the upscale. What I would like to be able to do is only scale down images to the respective transform values, but if smaller, then keep their size, thus avoiding the pixellation and extra unnecessary file size.

Any tips?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Added feature request here: http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/10007034-image-transforms-have-option-not-to-scale-up

Comment: Thanks @carlcs that solved it, however it would be great if it were a feature in the CP... this will do for now. :-)

Comment: Yes, I couldn't believe there was no feature request yet. Upvoted yours!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the only option at the moment is to follow this post's technique:

[Prevent Asset Transforms from scaling Image past 100%](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/prevent-asset-transforms-from-scaling-image-past-100)

Hopefully it will be implemented in the CP in the future... according to this feature request:

https://plus.google.com/110881688132908256910/posts/FAzrGAJ99W7